# No output when code is run Microsoft visual studio. right after install

Tags: visual-studio-code, mingw

I recently installed microsoft visual studio code and i cant seem to get my code to output. i know the code is corrrect. there doesnt seeem to be a code output window

i tried some tips from a youtube video but nothing is working

Comment: Which is it? Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? They are different things. Either fix your title or fix your tags please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it is visual studio code. the code seems to run ok with no errors but if I go to the output tab there is nothing just a blank screen.